# How to get source files from .apk file?

Tags: android

i am new to android application development.
I developed one android application.I build and install .apk file in my mobile.
Now i lost that source file.i have only the .apk file.
Is it possible to recover all my source file from that .apk file.
I developed my application in eclipse with android 4.0 version
please help me to go forward.
thank you,
bye.

Comment: Check [android-apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) which can be used for reverse engineering of APK files. Check and read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java class files are converted to dex files and are packed along with the other resource, You can use any [file compressing](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) software to get the contents of the apk file however to get the source code is difficult

How to get the java source code
The dex files are which contain the java source code, The [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) tool can be used to get the jar file from the dex file and once you get the jar file use [JD-GUI](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306011720/http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to get the source code in java. Now keep this in mind that if the user has used obfuscation then the java code you would get is obfuscated and you have to [DeObfuscator(I havent used this)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdo/)

To get other resources
You can used the [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to reverse engineer the code and other resources, [Here in XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1891686) you can get to know how to use it

Comment: dex2jar worked for me